# Why won't my python program in IDLE let me open and read a file?

Tags: python, computer-science

I'm trying to open a file named alldata.numbers using this code but I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'alldata.numbers'
```

This is my code:

```
    def main():
        # Asks user for filename
        inName = input("What is the filename? ")
        # Open file and read first line
        inFile = open(inName, "r")
        for i in range():
            data = inFile.readline()
            print(data)
        return
    main()
```

The file alldata.numbers is on my desktop with my saved code. How can I fix this so I can open any file?

Comment: Your python program is probably running in the wrong directory. Try providing the absolute path instead, or using `os.chdir()`

Comment: Also, try checking the current working directory using `print(os.getcwd())`

Answer (score 0):

changed the code to:

```
def main():
    # Asks user for filename
    inName = input("What is the filename for input? ")
    # Open file and read first line
    inFile = open(inName, "r")
    for line in inFile:
        inFile = inFile.readline()
        print(inFile)
    return
main()
```

Works now :)

Comment: Note that it is best practice to close files when you're done reading from them, `inFile.close()` before returning should do the trick.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_close.htm